# technique for remembering url

Tags: php, url, redirect

I am trying to achieve a functionality that is able to redirect a user to the URL/address to which he was trying to have access before logging in.

For example:

1. A user is trying to access a registered members only area.
2. He is given the message that he is not logged in and redirected to the index page.

How do I redirect the user to the 'Step 1' URL when he logs-in successfully?

I hope I am able to explain what I am trying to do.

thanks (in advance) for any help and suggestions :-)

Comment: The rep graph shows no downvote ever cast on this question. Are you trying to get pity upvotes?

Comment: I would recommend a title change to something like "Technique for remembering a users intended URL across http requests" or something that gives a little more details of the problem.

Comment: not at all Mr. e.c.ho but when I first posted this question it was voted down straight away. I have now deleted that comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass that URL in the URL itself:

```
if (!$loggedIn) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/login?return='.urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    exit;
}
```

And after the successful login:

```
if ($loginSucessful) {
    if (isset($_GET['return']) && substr($_GET['return'], 0, 1) == '/')) {
        header('Location: http://example.com'.$_GET['return']);
    } else {
        header('Location: http://example.com/');
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Note that I made a rough validation on the `return` value.

Comment: I do something like this except I store it to a session instead of in the URL

Answer (score 6):

store the request url in a hidden field in the login form and once logged in redirect to that url

Comment: You could also try using a session variable

Answer (score 3):

Store it in the session (or maybe even a cookie) before redirecting to the login page

Answer (score 3):

In the past I have redirected back to the authentication page with the "final destination" page having a redirect URL:  http://example.com/login?redirect=/secured/resource.

Remember to URL encode the parameter value.  Also, when you are processing the value of the redirect URL, make sure that it is a URL on your site or a relative URL to avoid any security attacks like a phishing scheme.  Otherwise, a third party can target your site's login page and then redirect back to their site and might have access to the user's secured session.

The reason I don't use the session to store the URL, is that search engine spiders can end up creating sessions as they hit links on your site that are secured and require login.  Since they have to credentials, the session is created just to timeout 30 minutes later.

Answer (score 2):

Storing in the session is much better. It allows the user to follow a link (for example a registration link) and to still be redirected to the original page after logging in.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen forums put it into the URL, something like www.myurl.com?prevUrl=<prevUrl>. Of course the url stored has to be encoded with encodeURI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something I really love: HTTP authentication. That way you don't have a redirect to a special Login page in between and deep links work as they should. Trac gets this right, imho.

The other option is that you store the URL in the session you likely are creating. If you don't destroy the session on login then you can use that to redirect to the deep link after login.

Comment: http auth is not very secure, however

Comment: warren: What is lacking? If you want security (i. e. privacy from eavesdroppers and knowledge that the other party really is who you expect it to be) then you use SSL. Same for every other thing you throw through HTTP.